# Dereference array within an array in one statement?

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array, dereference

```
@arr1 = ([1,2,3], 4, 5, 6);
$arr_ref = $arr1[0];
@arr2 = @$arr_ref;
```

Is it possible to do lines 2 and 3 in one statement?

I have tried `@arr2 = @$arr1[0];` but it doesn't compile.

Comment: Just syntax -- `@{$arr1[0]}`

Comment: http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add the braces because of the precedence rules

```
@arr2 = @{$arr1[0]};
```

From [perldsc, Caveat on precedence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#CAVEAT-ON-PRECEDENCE)

> Speaking of things like `@{$AoA[$i]}`
>   [ ... ]
>   That's because Perl's precedence rules on its five prefix dereferencers (which look like someone swearing: `$` `@` `*` `%` `&` ) make them bind more tightly than the postfix subscripting brackets or braces!

---

This implies that if explicit indexing isn't needed then there is no need for `{}`, for instance in code that retrieves array elements already. For example, to flatten an array with arrayrefs inside, per [Sobrique](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2566198/sobrique)'s comment

```
@all_elems = map { ref $_ eq "ARRAY" ? @$_ : $_ } @arr1;
```

To retrieve content of only arrayrefs one can use `: ()` instead of `: $_` in the ternary operator inside the block.  The `()` returns an empty list that gets flattened in the result thus not affecting it. (When the condition evaluates to false *something* has to be returned. This trick allows `map` to do `grep`'s work, effectively filtering.)

Comment: There's also `map`: `@arr2 = map { ref $_ eq "ARRAY" ? @$_ : $_ } @arr1;`

Comment: @Sobrique  Nice, avoids explicit indexing so no precedence problems.  This flattens the whole thing though, no? (Which is useful!)  For this question, perhaps `: ()` instead of `: $_`?

Comment: Yeah, it flattens it. `()` would work, but it'd discard that element, which may or may not be what's desired.